# PHPUnit - Don't fail when the dataProvider returns an empty array

Tags: phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test which uses a `@dataProvider`. The dataprovider checks the filesystem for certain files.

However I'm using this test in different environments what means it can happen that the files do not exist. This means that the dataProvider does not find anything and that the test is not executed.

And this causes the test run to end in a failure.

Question: is the a way to configure PHPUnit to ignore tests which have providers that produce nothing?

Comment: The answers below treat having PHPUnit report the test was skipped as an acceptable answer. But that's not an acceptable answer if you want PHPUnit to ignore the test entirely. Recording the skip is not ignoring the test. In my shop, a test run with skipped tests is not a clean run. An empty array should mean that the provider is providing no tests, not that there are tests to skip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I do not know of any phpunit option (which doesn't mean one doesn't exist), you could just use something like the following:

```
public function providerNewFileProvider()
{
    //get files from the "real" provider
    $files = $this->providerOldFileProvider();
    //no files? then, make a fake entry to "skip" the test
    if (empty($files)) {
        $files[] = array(false,false);
    }

    return $files;
}

/**
* @dataProvider providerNewFileProvider
*/

public function testMyFilesTest($firstArg,$secondArg)
{
    if (false === $firstArg) {
        //no files existing is okay, so just end immediately
        $this->markTestSkipped('No files to test');
    }

    //...normal operation code goes here
}
```

It's a workaround, sure, but it should stop an error from showing up. Obviously, whatever you do will depend on whether the first (or any arbitrary) argument is allowed to be `false`, but you can make tweaks to fit your tests.

Comment: +1 Though I would use `self::markTestSkipped('No files to test')` for clarity. And you need to annotate the test with `@dataProvider providerNewFileProvider` of course.

Comment: I'm going to wait a little bit for others to respond before I accept this answer, but I think this is the only correct solution. If I have a test which doesn't run then it would leave a 'gap' in the coverage, so I guess the PHPUnit people would expect it to run or to be skipped.

Comment: Data providers are called way before executing any tests, because PHPUnit wants to do some calculations of how many tests are being executed. It is debatable whether a data provider should return an empty array as a use case or not, but in general they are there to return the data to execute the test - not doing it usually is an error. If it is not, making the tester add code to reflect this deviation from the general case is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the « array(false, false) » solution that made my tests work fine !

Answer (score 4):

You can mark a test as skipped **in the data provider** as well, so it won't fail, nor you have to add a wrapper data provider as suggested in the other answer.

```
public function fileDataProvider()
{
    $files = $this->getTestFiles();
    if (empty($files)) {
        $this->markTestSkipped('No files to test');
    }

    return $files;
}

/**
 * @dataProvider fileDataProvider
 */

public function testMyFilesTest($firstArg, $secondArg)
{
    //...normal operation code goes here
}
```