# PHPUnit - Ignore test with data provider

Tags: phpunit

I have a trait with two tests, each of which has a separate data provider:

```
trait StringTest
{
  /**
   * @dataProvider stringProvider
   */
  public function testString($expression, $string)
  {
      //echo $name;
      $this->assertInternalType('string', $string, "Not a string.");
      $this->assertRegExp($expression, $string);
  }

  /**
   * @dataProvider nonmatchingStringProvider
   */
  public function testNonmatchingString($expression, $string)
  {
      //echo $name;
      $this->assertInternalType('string', $string, "Not a string.");
      $this->assertNotRegExp($expression, $string);
  }
}
```

I have test classes that have cases to test with `testString` but not with `nonmatchingStringProvider`. I want to ignore `testNonmatchingString` altogether when I don't have any cases for `nonmatchingStringProvider`. Ignore completely. Not report any sort of error, warning, or skip. (In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855492/phpunit-dont-fail-when-the-dataprovider-returns-an-empty-array) the developer accepted a solution that marks the test as skipped. A skip is not acceptable here.)

I could break the trait into two separate traits. I would prefer not to do that.

Is it possible to code or configure phpunit to behave this way, either by omitting `nonmatchingStringProvider` in the class or defining `nonmatchingStringProvider` and having it return an empty array?

Comment: Why don't you simple remote the test? It is dead anyway and tests nothing... Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's in a trait. Multiple test suites use it. Not all of those test suites will test for non-matching strings.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to skip single tests so I am afraid you will have to have two traits. At the end as you said: Not every test needs to test for not matching strings. Two different use cases, two different traits. You can also try with the default implementation for `nonmatchingStringProvider` but your tests may still report issues because such tests won't do any assertions. I would go for splitting traits.

Comment: I have another case with the same problem, but the common code is in an extended abstract class instead of a trait. Splitting the common code into multiple units isn't an option in this case.